# Encryption Algorithms in Verilog code

Tags: encryption, aes, des, rc4

Can we implement Encryption Algorithms like RC4,AES and DES in Verilog? if no what are the limitations?

Comment: Many groups have crypto in verilog before building their ASICs.  For example, here is an [opencores DES in Verilog](http://opencores.org/project,systemcdes).

Answer (score 3):

Verilog is [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), so you can implement any algorithm in Verilog, if you really want to.

Comment: Yup, you can implement as said above - Verilog is Turing complete -> No limitations